# Masonry - couldn't get the images fit in the whole container

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tried Mansonry with imageLoaded for dynamic image post - then the images (grey) appear in grid from left and right (padding space is about 10px).

The problem is that when I resize the browser larger (or smaller), the grid has quite some empty space on right which should be close to the right edge of browser with 15px in similar way to left edge.

see image example.[image]

**html**

```
<div class="bdy h-clearfix des">
    <div class="pure-u grid">
        <div class="masonry">
      <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="images/1.jpg"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="images/2.jpg"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="images/3.jpg"></div>

    </div>
        </div>
```

**JS**

```
var container = document.querySelector(".masonry");
 // initialize Masonry
 var msnry = new Masonry(container, {
      columnWidth: 50,
      itemSelector: '.item',
      gutter: 5,
      transitionDuration: 0,
      isFitWidth: true,
      animate:false,
      isResizable: true,

    });

imagesLoaded( container, function() {
  msnry.layout();
});
```

See: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bULPf/)

Any way to force the images (in gray) to fill in the whole container whether resize or not?

Help appreciated!

Comment: Code and fiddle please.

Comment: yea i m working on this now.

Comment: @MatthewJohnson jsfiddle is up. resize the screen and you will see what i mean by right edge with empty space

Comment: You'll probably need to use CSS media queries to adjust the column width to get it perfect.  [This site](http://osvaldas.info/responsive-jquery-masonry-or-pinterest-style-layout) has a good tutorial for it.

Comment: and i am trying isotope with mansonry. how to call imageloaded? there is no info on that